# Access Multiple Google Calendars using Java Script - Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have this code where I can get the event from my calendar.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
</head>
<body>
 <!--Add a button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
 <button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize</button>
 <button id="insert-button" style="visibility: hidden">Insert</button>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      // Enter a client ID for a web application from the Google Developer Console.
      // The provided clientId will only work if the sample is run directly from
      // https://google-api-javascript-client.googlecode.com/hg/samples/authSample.html
      // In your Developer Console project, add a JavaScript origin that corresponds to the domain
      // where you will be running the script.
      var clientId = '823958590548-s5b4d4ngoj6tj2misdvrcdm3rt27jolr.apps.googleusercontent.com';

      // Enter the API key from the Google Developer Console - to handle any unauthenticated
      // requests in the code.
      // The provided key works for this sample only when run from
      // https://google-api-javascript-client.googlecode.com/hg/samples/authSample.html
      // To use in your own application, replace this API key with your own.
      var apiKey = 'AIzaSyDTqOkVPgBv5kCIqp5NXp7UwE0MKTjLmrU';

      // To enter one or more authentication scopes, refer to the documentation for the API.
      var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

      // Use a button to handle authentication the first time.
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
      }

      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
      }


      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        var insertButton = document.getElementById('insert-button');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          makeApiCall();
          insertButton.style.visibility = '';
          insertButton.onclick = handleInsertClick;
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';

          insertButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';

          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        }
      }

      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      function handleInsertClick(event) {
       makeInsertApiCall();
      }

      function makeApiCall() {
       gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
         var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
           'calendarId': 'ashishpandit2312@gmail.com'
         });

         request.execute(function(resp) {
           for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
             var li = document.createElement('li');
             li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.items[i].summary));
             document.getElementById('events').appendChild(li);
           }
         });
       });
     }

      function makeInsertApiCall() {
       gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
         var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
           "calendarId": "primary",
           resource:{
               "summary": "Meeting",
               "location": "Somewhere",
               "start": {
                 "dateTime": "2015-02-21T01:00:00.000-07:00"
               },
               "end": {
                 "dateTime": "2015-02-21T04:25:00.000-08:00"
               }
             }
         });

         request.execute(function(resp) {
           for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
             console.dir(resp);
           }
         });
       });
     }

    </script>
 <script
  src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
 <div id='content'>
  <h1>Events</h1>
  <ul id='events'></ul>
 </div>

 <p>Connecting to Google Calendar with the Javascript Library.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the events from multiple Google Calendars. What changes should I make to make it work and access multiple calendars of different people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access multiple calendars of different people, the best way is to create a service account (which will do all requests to API's on behalf of users). So, users are not prompted with consent screen for authentication for accessing their calendar. Here are the steps:

1. Create a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and you as the admin for the domain.
2. Share all the calendars to this service account.
3. For the service account to access users data, follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation) for domain wide delegation.

Check this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2) for service account sample code in java.

Comment: Thanx for the help. Is there some way I can modify this code and authorize more than one google calendar by using the code that I already have and by using the web application option of the credentials that I have used.